# PHP Multiple Sessions ot GET/POST over multiple pages

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am new to PHP, just trying to finish my first app...
It's a real estate page. 
User may add info for open house. Code directs to add general info. Then Picture. This route works very well with session. There is log in system. Same user would add new open house and edit current ones all while logged in.

There is a link to Edit Account which at this point users can edit whatever, inclusive listings, add pictures, etc. 
But when I go this route, the session brings he same values for address from the first info entry, and not for the item to be edited.

My guess is that I basically have two routes:
a) have two sessions at the same time
**Question**: how to differentiate them? How to call them? I just can't understand php.net yet. Maybe within a few months. I tried.

b) I learned (after a lot of sweat and endless nights) the very basic _POST using the URL. But the way i learned it is mostly useful for consecutive pages. I need to go through multiple hoops...

**Question**: Is there a way to keep passing the post and get values over several different pages? Or create a global variable?

Is there a better way to do this besides what I have researched?

Thank you for you time.

**EDIT**EDIT**

I was asked to put some code here. 
Once I get all info for the open house, I have one file that insert all data in DB, and gets address, city and state to geocode address in order to insert data (lat , lng) in DB

```
$username = $_SESSION['user']['username'];

$sql="INSERT INTO braaasil_brokerstour.property(day, hours,laundry_equip, VERY LONG QUERY, ETC.)
VALUE ('$_POST[day]','$_POST[hours]','$_POST[laundry_equip]',VERY LONG QUERY, ETC. ETC'$username')"
    or die ("fail");  

if (!mysqli_query($connection,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
  }

$P_ID = $connection->insert_id;
printf ("New Record has id:  %d.\n", $P_ID);
$_SESSION['P_ID']   = $P_ID;
ETC. ETC.
```

Than, I get a few values in SESSION to use in different pages.

```
<?php session_start(); 
$address = $_SESSION['address'];
$city = $_SESSION['city'];
$zip_code = $_SESSION['zip_code'];
$P_ID = $_SESSION ['P_ID'];
```

The problem is that the same user may add a new listing and fix old stuff and the session is there. It would be nice that pageInsertNew.php (the geocode stuff) gets one session. The pageFIX.php (update/fix stuff) creates a different session. This way I could separate stuff.

I will use this info about ID and address to insert pictures in different table with user's ID and address to make sure we can easily debug if something goes wrong.

I **really appreciate** all the answers. But I need a full day to understand them, study them, and I will get back. I am new here, but i think you may get an email with any change I do here.

Thank you again for all the responses. I have no idea how to implement them today, let's hope things will change soon.

Besides there is this issue between some people who like post/get and some people prefer session. I am in no position to judge this at this point with my computer skills.

**EDIT #2**
Thank you imsiso. 
These is the second source of values that I need (first one is above in this question). Both have the same names (address, city, zip_code). Both to be used by the same user either in the same session or not.

```
<?php
  require_once('config.php');       

   $query = sprintf("select P_ID, address, city from property WHERE username =  '".(
                 htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))."'");

    $result = mysql_query($query, $db);

    $images = array();

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $address = $_SESSION['address'];
      $city = $_SESSION['city'];
      $zip_code = $_SESSION['zip_code'];
      $P_ID = $_SESSION ['P_ID'];
         echo $P_ID;
        echo $city;


 ?><br />

Edit pictures:

<form action="formAddPic2.php" method="post">
<li> <a href="formAddPic2.php?P_ID=<?php echo $row['P_ID']; ?>">Property ID: <?php  print  $row['P_ID'] ?> </a><br /><br />
&ensp;&ensp;  Address: <?php print $row['address']?>,   <?php print $row['city'] ; ?> 
</li>  
<form>
<?php
```

As you see, I had abondoned the session and gone back to get/post just of the property ID, but now I need to get also values for the address just in case I start to have problems.

Therefore, after one loop, this is what I will try:

```
$properties=array(
/* like:    id=>array(
        'id'=>id
    ),*/
    1=>array(
        'id'=>1,
        'property_name'=>'echo $row['P_ID']',    // automatic id in database
         'zip_code => 'echo $row['zip_code']',
        'some_other_things'=>'some other value',
    ),
    2=>array(
        'id'=>2,
        'property_name'=>'echo $row['P_ID']',    // automatic id in database
         'zip_code => 'echo $row['zip_code']',
        'some_other_things'=>'some other value',
    ),

);

$_SESSION['properties']=array();
$_SESSION['properties']=$properties;
```

So, the array will go after the loop, than I just call the values as in the @imsiso' answer. 
Also, one loop may be always empty depending whether user has to add new listing and fix old stuff or just fix or just add new stuff.

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION);` to check how many session you are having at the same time

Comment: if you are doing it well with sessions for one item use session in array format to handle others.

Comment: `SESSION` variables can be very helpful. Avoid using `GLOBALS` at all costs and depending upon how long you want a variable to stick around, you could even use `COOKIES`.

Comment: like `$_SESSION['products']=array(1=>array('id'=>1,'name'=>'test'/*,...*/),2=>array('id'=>2,'name'=>'test2'/*,...*/));`

Comment: Use POST/GET to submit your data, use SESSIONS to keep its state.

Comment: The problem with sessions is that they are set from the browser, and browsers differs slightly in the ways they manage them (firefox is the most horrible one), if you really need to have multiple sessions from a single browser, you'll have to manage a tree inside your own session, with the top entries something application wide, this won't be written in a few code lines.

Comment: please add some code of what you have done so far.

Comment: I am not sure if I add one comment here everyone gets the info. Thank you all. I added something in main question upon request. See EDIT Thank you again.

Comment: @djot "SESSIONs to keep its state". You mean keep values over a session? Yes, i used post and get to submit data. The problem is to keep some values.

Comment: @user2060451 This is exactly what I mean. Everything that should stay alive over requests, should be assigned to a/the SESSION. Like `$_SESSION['user']['username'] = $_POST['user_name']; $_SESSION['other']['stuff'] = $foo;` ... If you are not familiar with SESSIONS read some tutorial (= the basics) first before asking further questions.

Comment: @user2060451 - first because you are new here. check these http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and If you have a long question you should set a bonty for it. and I think it can be posted as another question. (I mean there is no reason to put all questions in a project as one question.seprate them). BUT IM READING it.

Answer (score 1):

You know you have one session. But you often need to save a variety of data in sessions like authentication who is logged in, what he is doing, forms in several page, buying basket,etc.

and if you want to handle session easy you should use a session handler class (for setting and getting session value easily and also for security)

Or at least you should use arrays in sessions like this.

```
$_SESSION['user_data']=array();
$_SESSION['user_data']['is_logged_in']='yes';
$_SESSION['user_data']['user_id']=106;
$_SESSION['user_data']['user_name']='john';

$products=array(
/* like:    id=>array(
        'id'=>id
    ),*/
    1=>array(
        'id'=>1,
        'product_name'=>'house 1',
        'some_other_things'=>'some other value',
    ),
    2=>array(
        'id'=>2,
        'product_name'=>'house 2',
        'some_other_things'=>'some other value',
    ),
    4=>array(
        'id'=>4,
        'product_name'=>'house 3',
        'some_other_things'=>'some other value',
    ),
);

$_SESSION['products']=array();
$_SESSION['products']=$products;
```

---

**Updated:** description added.

Yes you are right the actual array is

```
$products=array(
    0=>array('id'=>35,'address'=>'somewhere 1'),
    1=>array('id'=>36,'address'=>'somewhere 2')
);
```

which is equal with:

```
$products=array(
    array('id'=>35,'address'=>'somewhere 1'),
    array('id'=>38,'address'=>'somewhere 2')
);
```

But I myself used the product_id instead of default index. like:

```
$products=array(
    35=>array('id'=>35,'address'=>'somewhere 1'),
    38=>array('id'=>38,'address'=>'somewhere 2')
);
```

now I can access to data of product with Id equal to 2 by this:

```
$product[2];
```

if I had not done that the I had too search all products to find that. That's kind of a trick maybe but it's being used in many places and can help you too.(in other similar things).

Comment: Please bear with me. My six month experience with computers (from css to PHP) knocks me over every day. Inside the array - that 'id' is different from the user_id, right? All need now is to have session with two cities, two zipcodes, tow addresses etc. So $products=array ( 'id'=>1, 'addres' => '123 abc st'), 2=>array ('id'='2', 'address' => '456 bdf St',). How to call the right array? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Thank you. I will study your answer and it seems to be the right way. i will get back.

Comment: First, Thank you VERY much. I added a new peace of code, please see EDIT #2. The way I was adding the session was to have it up in the start, but having it first after the first time the values were called, like while iterating some loop, call the session there, and then on top of pages that I need the values. Basic usage. It's just a matter of names, but my case is about houses. So I need to have one session with one user trying to accomplish two things. Please see rest in main question.

Comment: I am with you. Thank you and I will try to figure it out trying to follow your suggestion. I din't find anything in the net with similar problems, it's an advanced problem. Then I didn't know I could have an array there, so I could not even study/google it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too clear with the context of the question; however, these pointers will be of help -

Its a very bad idea to store intermediate data in session. Webservers are meant to be stateless. (Look it up). The only stateful information that the webserver could store is login identifier; and that's it - this is a very clean design. Even if posting takes a while, you could use it.

An alternate route is to go JS. You could store data in html5 sessionStorage - this is perfect for what you are doing. You could consider html5 localStorage too; and post the data all at once.

FYI - a session is tracked via PHP_SESSIONID cookie. If the pages are on the same domain/subdomain, two different sessions cannot be created; however different session variable names can be used. Also note - most login system create new session identifiers.